# What is the right way to substitute column values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to following thing to happen:

for every column in df check if its type is numeric, if not - use label encoder to map str/obj to numeric classes (e.g 0,1,2,3...).

I am trying to do it in the following way:

```
for col in df:
    if not np.issubdtype(df[col].dtype, np.number):
        df[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[col])
```

I see few problems here.

First - column names can repeat and thus `df[col]` returns more than one column, which is not what I want.

Second - `df[col].dtype` throws error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

which I assume might arise due to the issue #1 , e.g we get multiple columns returned. But I am not confident.

Third - would assigning `df[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[col])` lead to a column substitution in df or should I do some esoteric df partitioning and concatenation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `LabelEncoder` supports only one column at a time, iteration over columns is your only option. You can make this a little more concise using `select_dtypes` to select the columns, and then `df.apply` to apply the `LabelEncoder` to each column.

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number]).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: LabelEncoder().fit_transform(x))
```

Alternatively, you could build a mask by selecting object dtypes only (a little more flaky but easily extensible):

```
m = df.dtypes == object
# m = [not np.issubdtype(d, np.number) for d in df.dtypes]
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].apply(lambda x: LabelEncoder().fit_transform(x))
```